# Best way to execute code after an event from another class occurs in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Let's say we have `form A` that has a button 'Run Wizard'. Clicking this button opens up a wizard to create something. This wizard is imported from another project, which form A references. The wizard, during its work, creates several arrays.

This is the code from clicking the button:

```
private void buttonOpenWizard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SampleWizard wizard = new SampleWizard();
            wizard.Show();
            //(theoretical code using arrays created by the wizard)
        }
```

What is the best way to wait for the wizard to complete, and run the theoretical code only after completing the wizard task?

Comment: Creating a task might help you

Comment: Does the `Show()` method block and wait until the wizard is done, or is it asynchronous? Does the wizard provide APIs to access the data that it collects? I'm assuming that it's going to need to do the latter, and the answer to your question would depend on the answer to my first question.

Comment: If you don't mind blocking the original form during the wizard, use `ShowDialog`.

Comment: @TusharGupta could you explain it to me further?

Comment: @JLRishe it is asynchronous; and yes, I can easily access the data from Form A. (Maybe a lock or something like that?)

Comment: @Chris I don't mind blocking, but how to do it? :)

Comment: Posted it as an answer..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't seem to mind blocking, use `ShowDialog`:

```
private void buttonOpenWizard_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    SampleWizard wizard = new SampleWizard();
    if( wizard.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ) // this line will block until the wizard form is closed
    {
        // and any code here will not run until that has happened
    }
}
```

Normally you use the return value from  the `ShowDialog` call to indicate if the user completed the wizard/dialog or not. In this case there's no way for me to know if that form uses that or not, but here I've assumed it does.

If you do not wish to block, you should be able to do something like this:

```
private void buttonOpenWizard_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    SampleWizard wizard = new SampleWizard();
    wizard.FormClosed += WizardClosed; // hook up event handler
    wizard.Show();
}

private void WizardClosed( object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e )
{
    var wizard = (SampleWizard)sender;
    // check and use result of wizard here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know about the difference between Show and ShowDialog. By the way, just out of curiosity, if I did mind blocking, how would it be solvable?

Comment: One way would be to hook an event handler to the `FormClosed` event of the form, show it using the normal `Show` method, and then do processing in the event handler.

Comment: Could you edit your answer with the code perhaps? Just for the future. Merry Christmas! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
private void buttonOpenWizard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SampleWizard wizard = new SampleWizard();
        if(wizard.ShowDialog()== DialogResult.OK) //Set the dialog result to ok in your form, if it would closed corret
        {
         //(theoretical code using arrays created by the wizard)
        }

    }
```